# 500 internal server error codeigniter ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

me sale este error al momento de insertar datos de un formulario a una base de datos mysql, no se como solucionarlo :(

ajax

```
<script>
        $(document).on("click", "#agregar", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
            var apellidop = $("#apellidop").val();
            var apellidom = $("#apellidom").val();
            var correo = $("#correo").val();
            var telefono = $("#telefono").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>insert",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    nombre: nombre,
                    apellidop: apellidop,
                    apellidom: apellidom,
                    correo: correo,
                    telefono: telefono
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Welcome.php (controller)

```
 ***
```

1. ---

   ```
   1. <?php
          defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

          class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

           public function __construct()
           {
               parent::__construct();
               $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
               $this->load->library('form_validation');
               $this->load->model('aplicacion_model');
           }

           public function index()
           {
               $this->load->view('welcome_message');
           }

           public function insert(){
               if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre', 'required');
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('apellidop', 'Apellidop', 'required');
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('apellidom', 'Apellidom', 'required');
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'Correo', 'required|valid_email');
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono', 'Telefono', 'required');

                   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                          {
                             $data = array('responce' => 'error', 'message' => validation_errors());
                          }
                          else
                          {
                          $ajax_data = $this->input->post();   
                          if($this->aplicacion_model->insert_entry($ajax_data)){
                               $data = array('responce' => 'success', 'message' => 'Datos agregados con éxito');
                          }else{
                               $data = array('responce' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error');
                          }   
                          }
               }else{
                   echo "No direct script access allowed";
               }
               echo json_encode($data);
           }
          }
      ***
   ```

---

Aplicacion_model.php

```
<?php 

class Aplicacion_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_last_ten_entries()
    {
            $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
            return $query->result();
    }

    public function insert_entry($data)
    {
            return $this->db->insert('aplicacion', $data);
    }

    public function update_entry()
    {
            $this->title    = $_POST['title'];
            $this->content  = $_POST['content'];
            $this->date     = time();

            $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: El error 500 puede ser varias cosas, si compartes el detalle que te muestra en el error sería de mucha utilidad, saludos.

Comment: @Sairento como podría expandir en este caso el detalle del error?

Comment: Puedes ver con mas detalles desde la network en tu navegador, es decir si abres la consola de tu navegador desde desde la pestaña donde tienes tu proyecto habrá una opción que dice network o red, ejecuta todo el proceso de nuevo y envía tu formulario ahí se mostrarán todas las peticiones que estás mandado ya sea POST o GET, una vez te salga la petición con el error  `500 ` has click ahí y en la pestaña llamada  `Response` te debe salir el detalle del error

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu ajax
Concretamente en la url, la cual debería ser así

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/insert",
```

Te ha faltado el nombre del controlador en la url para acceder a un método de este